# How is the Stack Overflow vote system handled?

Tags: support, voting

I want to know how the Stack Overflow vote system is handled because there are many votes in a day and handling of it is very complex.

Comment: What do you mean, how is it handled?

Comment: yes i want to know basis on which it is handled

Comment: He's asking how we keep track of voting on such a large scale, which is on topic :)

Comment: @TimPost How stackoverflow solves race condition on database. If SO locks table others will wait for that row. If SO doesn't lock it will be problem too.

Comment: @TimPost Stackoverflow also tracks view count. And how SO solves that. Is view system and vote system works properly. Is there any race condition? or is there any slow query which when that row locked others are waiting?

Comment: @TimPost Stackoverflow also tracks view count. And how SO solves that. Is view system and vote system works properly. Is there any race condition? or is there any slow query which when that row locked others are waiting?

Comment: @Nbody I have not worked for Stack in years; I'm sorry, I can't help you with that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They use really fast database servers, and a few tricks.  The votes are stored in their own table, one row per vote, but each time a post is voted on, that post's row in the post table has a total score that is also modified up or down.

So when you vote, a record is created, and the post's record is modified.  When you request a page you only need to see the total, not the individual votes, so the voting table is ignored, and there's no calculation to be done, it just returns the current score from the post table.

When you click the score, if you have the privilege, it does query the voting table for that post, does the calculation, and returns the total up and total down votes.  This doesn't happen unless it's specifically requested by a user, though, so even though it hits the database harder than the post score, it's not used very frequently by users, relative to the number of times pages are requested.

Very fast servers, separation of voting record from post score.

Comment: It's basically the same today. That's why seeing the up/down count is a separate request (and not available to everyone).

Comment: ...(and can only be done once a second per user).

Comment: So how stackoverflow Solves race condition on voting system. If SO locks the row it will be slow. If SO doesn't lock that row it will be problem too

Comment: Stackoverflow also tracks view count. And how SO solves that. Is view system and vote system works properly. Is there any race condition? or is there any slow query which when that row locked others are waiting?